# SQL Statement for ExecuteNonQuery in C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, executenonquery

I am trying to insert a new row into a table in my `SQL` database through a `webform`.

The problem is that I need to place the `DateTime` value in the Description of when the assignment of deliveryman was done.

But because the value is a string and the requirement is to display something like this `"Received parcel by StationMgrSG on 19 July 2016 10:34am"` but my codes is displaying something like this "Received parcel by StationMgrSG on @TimeNow"

How do i change the value so that it displays the date and time?

This is my code:

```
public int updateDeliveryHistory()
    {

        string strConn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["NPCSConnectionString"].ToString();

        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(strConn);

        SqlCommand cmad = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO DELIVERYHISTORY(ParcelID, Description) VALUES (@ParcelId,'Received parcel by StationMgrSG on @TimeNow')",conn);

        cmad.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ParcelId", parcelID);
        cmad.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TimeNow", DHCreateTime);

        conn.Open();

        cmad.ExecuteNonQuery();

        conn.Close();

        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

To achieve this you have to modify the code like this:

```
SqlCommand cmad = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO DELIVERYHISTORY(ParcelID, Description) VALUES (@ParcelId, @TimeNow)",conn);
cmad.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ParcelId", parcelID);
cmad.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TimeNow","Received parcel by StationMgrSG on " + DHCreateTime.ToString());
```

**Additional note**, You can specify the DateFormat inside the `.ToString()` method if needed. then the `@TimeNow` will looks like the following:

```
string formatString="dd-MMMM-yyyy HH:mm"
cmad.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TimeNow","Received parcel by StationMgrSG on " + DHCreateTime.ToString(formatString));
```

Comment: Even better if you have a DateTime column in the DB for this data.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change this line

```
SqlCommand cmad = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO DELIVERYHISTORY(ParcelID, Description) VALUES (@ParcelId,'Received parcel by StationMgrSG on @TimeNow')",conn);
```

to

```
SqlCommand cmad = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO DELIVERYHISTORY(ParcelID, Description) VALUES (@ParcelId,'Received parcel by StationMgrSG on ' + @TimeNow)",conn);
```

The problem is you're passing '@TimeNow' as part of a string literal instead of a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this:

```
 string getDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("MMMM dd yyyy hh:mmtt");

 SqlCommand cmad = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO DELIVERYHISTORY(ParcelID, Description) VALUES (@ParcelId,'Received parcel by StationMgrSG on ' + getDate)",conn);

 cmad.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ParcelId", parcelID);
 cmad.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TimeNow", getDate);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: That is Why, I told you to format your code, instead for down voting the post. [This will help you to post good answers](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: dont know yet how to format my code,, im just answering,, dont care if they down voted me.. maybe someday i know how to format it here.

Comment: Need to share my thought and give to other who needed it.. thanks @un-lucky